How to copy a folder into nuget package using BuildOutputInPackage
I am trying to copy a folder into a nuget package, on a multi-targeted project.
My input folder is Example, and I want it's content copied into a folder Example in the nuget package (for each lib version)
I am following the docs for BuildOutputInPackage: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/msbuild-targets#advanced-extension-points-to-create-customized-package
I have a .csproj with the following:
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk">
  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFrameworks>netstandard2.0;net48</TargetFrameworks>
  </PropertyGroup>

 <PropertyGroup>
   <TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>$(TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput);Example</TargetsForTfmSpecificBuildOutput>
 </PropertyGroup>

 <Target Name="Example">
   <ItemGroup>
     <BuildOutputInPackage Include="$(ProjectDir)Example\**\*.*">
       <TargetPath>Example</TargetPath>
     </BuildOutputInPackage>
   </ItemGroup>
 </Target>
</Project>

Given I have

Example/1.txt
Example/2.txt

Only the first file gets copied when TargetPath is present, and msbuild emits a warning: {File} not added because the package already contains file {TargetPath}
However if I remove TargetPath, all files are copied, but to the root directory.
How can I copy all files to a custom directory?

Add files as source to iterate over:
  <Target Name="Example">
    <ItemGroup>
      <Files Include="$(ProjectDir)Example\**\*.*" />
      <BuildOutputInPackage Include="%(Files.Identity)">
      <TargetPath>Example/%(Files.RecursiveDir)%(Files.Filename)%(Files.Extension)</TargetPath>
      </BuildOutputInPackage>
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>

